# JavaScript array sorts itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to write a bubble sort animation - for that I want to put all the iteration in the separate array and then reproduce them. But the `array` variable acts weird - all the `console.dir(array)` outputs are sorted arrays, so in the `pool` appears to be 9 identical arrays `[[1 ,2 ,3], [1, 2, 3] ... ]` I expect to see all the iteration of the sorting algorithm: `[[2, 3, 1], [2, 1, 3] ... ]]`

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong, and the most important, why `array` array is always sorted?

**Note**: Snippet works here, but doesn't work correctly in browser, or jsfiddle

Code snippet:

```js
    const pool = [];
    const bubbleSort = (array) => {
      const len = array.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
          if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
            const tmp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = tmp;
          }
          pool.push(array);
          console.dir(array);
        }
      }
    }

    bubbleSort([3, 2, 1]);
    console.log(pool);
```

Comment: I've tried multiple times in jsfiddle and in angular application - same result. BTW, jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/asqdg79b/2/

Comment: ha, interesting - it works only in REPL :)

Comment: If you insert code correctly - you can run it directly on SO! Fixed that for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I think has to do with the fact that JavaScript arrays sort of maintain something of a "pass by reference" kind of situation when you push to the `pool` stack. You can try

```
pool.push(array.slice()); // This creates a new instance of the array
```

You can also read this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable) for clarification on mutability of arrays

Answer (score 0):

you have to understand two things:

- the variable `array` refers to a mutable array. This means that each time you swap two elements, the array is modified
- when you do `pool.push(array)`, you push a *reference* into `pool`.

In your code, you push n times the same reference in `pool`.
So, you have only 2 arrays in memory: `pool` and `array` (i.e. `[3,2,1]` in your example)

Each time you modify `array` (by swapping elements), you modify all the arrays (in fact the *unique* array) stored in pool.

So, if you want to take a snapshot you have to store a copy of your array in pool: `pool.push(array.slice())`

Concerning the "weird" behaviour of `console.dir`, this comes from the asynchronous nature of this function. See [console.log() async or sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)